# zlib/libz.dylib decompression

Tags: php, objective-c, http-post, zlib, compression

I'm totally new to php and need some help with a script. can't figure out why the write doesn't work when the open works just fine. 
The file I receive is zipped using the `- (NSData *)compress:(NSData *)` [from this example](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?HTTPFileUploadSample) which use the libz.dylib framework.

code:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$dir = "upload/";
if(!file_exists($dir)){
    mkdir($dir);
}

$target = $dir . basename($_FILES['uploaded']['name']);

$zip = $target . ".gz";
$file = $target . ".jpeg";

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded']['tmp_name'], $zip))
{
    $arr = gzfile($zip);

    if(is_writable($dir)){
        if(! $fh = fopen($file, 'w')){
            echo "NO - cannot open file ($file)";
            exit;
        }

        foreach($arr as $value){
            if(fwrite($fh, $value) === FALSE){
                echo "NO - failed to write to file ($file)";
                exit;
            }
        }
        fclose($fh);
        echo "YES - successfully written to file ($file)";
    }
    else{
        echo "NO - folder ($dir) not writable";
    }
}
else {
    echo "NO - unable to move_uploaded_file";
}
?>
```

the decompression doesn't work. the post request is also the same as in the [example](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?HTTPFileUploadSample) above.
does anyone know what's wrong? what compression does the compress-method in the example use?  (deflate or compress or something else)

the code for the post looks like this:

```
- (NSURLRequest *)postRequestWithURL: (NSURL *)url  
                                data: (NSData *)data   // IN
                             boundry: (NSString *)boundry // IN
{
    // from http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?HTTPFileUpload
    NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest =
    [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [urlRequest setValue:
     [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundry]
      forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    NSMutableData *postData =
    [NSMutableData dataWithCapacity:[data length] + 512];
    [postData appendData:
     [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundry] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postData appendData:
     [[NSString stringWithFormat:
       @"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"; filename=\"test%d\"\r\n", FORM_FLE_INPUT, counter++]
      dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postData appendData: 
     [@"Content-Type: application/gzip\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postData appendData: 
     [@"Content-Encoding: gzip\r\n\r\n"dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postData appendData:data];
    [postData appendData:
     [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n", boundry] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [urlRequest setHTTPBody:postData];
    return urlRequest;
}
```

basically the same as in the example from cocoadev but i've added

```
[postData appendData: [@"Content-Type: application/gzip\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postData appendData: [@"Content-Encoding: gzip\r\n\r\n"dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

because i though this would help the `gfile($file)` but when i try to gunzip the .gz in terminal i still get the error **gzip: upload/test1.gz: not in gzip format**

I also read on [this site](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wci/v6r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.cast_iron.doc/compression_decompression_with_the_http_post_request_activity.html) that if I add **Content-Type = gzip** (as I do above) to the HTTP Post request the Integration Appliance will decompress the HTTP post body but I can't get this to work either. (I've tried this with the very simple php-script that is in the example from cocoadev, since I don't need the `gzfile()`-stuff in my php-scrip)

Answer (score 0):

try to enable warnings and notices outputs. it may help you to get more detailed information.
just put

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

at the first line of your code

Comment: depends on where do you run your script. if you launch it in command line interface, you see the warnings in console. if you run script via browser - the warnings will appear right in generated html code

Comment: Ok I run it in the browser and I only get the "NO2" still :/

Comment: it means, there's no warnings and notices)). can you share the file you're trying to upload?

Comment: i've got the php-script working and updated the question with the new code. problem is that decompression still doesn't work.